# web api action filter doesn't invoke, why?

Tags: asp.net-web-api-filters

I've created a webapi filter (it's using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core):

```
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
...
public class AuthenticationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
```

....
}

and use it in my controller:

```
[AuthenticationFilter]
public class MyController : SomeBaseController
```

than i'm adding into the bootstrpper using:

```
    _httpConfiguration.Filters.Add(new AuthenticationFilter());
```

the problem is that OnActionExecuting doesn't firing.

can u assist?

Answer (score 0):

It is not gonna fire if you dont add it to the services

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(SampleActionFilter));
});
```

I suggest to check out this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2) as well

Comment: i'm not sure it's related bbut im using owin pipline so i don't have this methods